# .Show that $H$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of $2n$ .Let H be a subgroup of $G$ consisting of only those elements of $G$ which are of order $\neq 2$.Suppose $o(H)=n$ Show that $n$ is odd and $H$ is  abelian.

Pairing the elements $(g,g^{-1})$ of $H$ since $g\neq g^{-1}\forall g\in H$.Also $H$ has identity $e$.Thus $o(H)=n=$ odd

How to show $H$ is  abelian.

Comment: This seems similar to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702692/prove-that-h-is-a-abelian-subgroup-of-odd-order, but there are some additional hypotheses that make the result make sense.

Comment: yes I have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Here is a counterexample:

Let $K$ be any non-abelian group of odd order.

Define $G= K \times (\frac{\mathbb Z}{2 \mathbb Z})$. Then $H= K \times (0+2 \mathbb Z)$ has the desire properties, but is not abelian.

Answer (score 0):

As N.S. points out, this question is incomplete.  The extra condition I've seen is this: $G\setminus H$ consists precisely of the elements of order $2$.

In this case, conjugating $H$ by one of those elements gives that $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is a homomorphism $H\to H$, which can only happen if $H$ is abelian.

Comment: yes I have edited the question